# How to get peer list?

Tags: discovery, jxta

I have a problem with jxta. 
I dont get peer list.

```
        @Override public void discoveryEvent(DiscoveryEvent event) {
           DiscoveryResponseMsg res = event.getResponse();
           Enumeration en = res.getAdvertisements();
            if (en != null) {
            while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            PeerAdvertisement a = (PeerAdvertisement)en.nextElement();
            Console.append(a.name()+"\n");
            }
           }
```

and

`discovery.getRemoteAdvertisements(null, DiscoveryService.PEER, null, null, 1, null);`

Console.append - is append to JTextArea. In this console print only one peer, but jxtanetwork have 3 peers. Where is error? 
P.S. I get code from [How do I discover peers and send messages in JXTA-JXSE 2.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910929/how-do-i-discover-peers-and-send-messages-in-jxta-jxse-2-6)
P.P.S Sorry for my bad english.. I'm hope for your help... Thanks

Comment: Oh, f*ck. I'm dummie. Problem is solved. discovery.getRemoteAdvertisements(null, DiscoveryService.PEER, null, null, **1**, null); - this is maximum of peer advertisement in each discovery response. If replace 1 on 5 (e.g.) - it's work.

Answer (score 0):

`1` is the issue, it is the maximum number of answers your will get back (1 is less than 3).